# How to use Binance api in laravel with Controller

Tags: laravel

I can't use binance api in laravel

I installed Php binance api from composer require "composer require jaggedsoft/php-binance-api" from "https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api" but examples not working in laravel.I had some errors when I tried.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Binance;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    
    public function index()
    {
        $api = new Binance\API();
    $key = "----";
    $secret = "---";
    $api = new Binance\API($key, $secret);

    $data = $api->price("BNBBTC");    
        return view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

When I runned the route I got this error:

```
    Error
    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Binance\API' not found
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
```

Comment: probably need to use `new \Binance\API`

Answer (score 0):

Either import the Binance on top of your file or use backslash `\`

Comment: I am not understand, can you please clarify it :(

Comment: When you try to use a class, in your example it's the Binance class, you should import it on the top of the file(use Binance/xxxxx) or add the backslash. 
    $api = new \Binance\API($key, $secret);